# Differences between Protector and Obfuscator for .Net

Tags: .net, deobfuscation, protector

I am currently looking for a replacement for our old Salamander protector due some unsolvable DLL load issues in the released software. I ran Google and found some solutions worthy to try. The website, of course, promises best security and an easy way to adapt the build process.

From the technical point of view. What is the real difference between Protector and Obfuscator? We use the delay signing feature and set the key later in the protection process. The private key is stored in a safe place and only the public key is commited to our SVN repository.

As far as I understand, an obfuscator just makes the code unreadable and difficult/impossible to copy. A protector signed the assembly and makes it impossible to modify, so that the assembly is safe to use.

At the moment the protector from Vgrsoft (http://www.vgrsoft.com) and the Crypto Obfuscator (http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) could be candidates for the replacement.

Comment: Recommending tool is offtopic for SO. Any tool worth using will probably have a free trial though. Test both and see which one fits your needs better.

Comment: I think it's more to marketing words playing (*because protectors also do obfuscation*). This software do one thing - protect your app.

Comment: Just use a telephone, companies are always happy to extol the virtues of their product.

Comment: It's more a technical question regarding the differences. Sorry for confusing you. I'll choose the tool on my own later.